# where did PixelFormats and WriteableBitmap.Lock go in Silverlight3?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, writeablebitmap

A few months ago I built some online samples like [this one from Jeff Prosise](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/03/23/silverlight-3-s-new-writeablebitmap.aspx) that use the WriteableBitmap class in Silverlight.

Revisiting them today with the latest Silverlight3 installer (3.0.40624.0), the API seems to have changed.

I figured out some of the changes.  For example, the WriteableBitmap array accessor has disappeared, but I found it in the new Pixels property, so instead of writing:

```
 bmp[x]
```

I can write

```
bmp.Pixels[x]
```

Are there similar simple replacements for these calls, or has the use pattern itself changed?

```
bmp = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, PixelFormats.Bgr32);
bmp.Lock();
bmp.Unlock();
```

Can anybody point me to a working example using the updated API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you don't use `Lock` and `Unlock` and just use the `WritabelBitmap(int, int)` constructor?  Do things break?

It would seem that between SL3 Beta and the release this API has changed. [See Breaking Changes Document Errata (Silverlight 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/07/01/breaking-changes-document-errata-silverlight-3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that changes document clarifies things.  (Alas I do then just get a blank screen, but maybe that's because of the Bgr32/Pbgra32 difference, or something else entirely.)

Answer (score 2):

Another important detail about switching to the new WriteableBitmap is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124369/silverlight-3-writeablebitmap-problem/1271974#1271974) ... because the pixel format is now always pbgra32, you must set an alpha value for each pixel, otherwise you just get an all-white picture.  In other words, code that formerly generated pixel values like this:

```
byte[] components = new byte[4];
components[0] = (byte)(blue % 256);       // blue
components[1] = (byte)(grn % 256);        // green
components[2] = (byte)(red % 256);        // red
components[3] = 0;                        // unused
```

should be changed to read:

```
byte[] components = new byte[4];
components[0] = (byte)(blue % 256);       // blue
components[1] = (byte)(grn % 256);        // green
components[2] = (byte)(red % 256);        // red
components[3] = 255;                      // alpha
```